# Vehicle Title Requirements for selling a junk car

Tags: united-states, car, ohio

I'm planning to sell my old car to a company that will scrap it. I'd like to know what do I need to do with the title?
They are planning to come and pick the car up and tow it to the junk yard.
I submitted the request through some website and the site says to sign the back of the title and have it notarized. The company who will pick up the car called and said not to do it.

So I'm confused. Can I just give them the title of the car and they will process the rest? Does anyone has any experience scraping car in Ohio and know the process?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but you might want to check if your vehicle has any "valuable" parts.  Pull 'em ahead of time and sell them online.

Comment: no, the car is Ford Taurus and I got it for 3k 6 years ago.

Comment: A signature can always be added later, by mail; it can't be removed. If in doubt I'd go with the "don't" sdvice.

Comment: Here is what the [Ohio BMV says](http://publicsafety.ohio.gov/links/bmv6341.pdf).

Comment: @Grasper It might still have a few valuable things, like the catalytic converter.

Comment: @Joe, they are going to pay me $35 and tow it for me cause I can't start it. Alternator is bad or the cables. Don't want to invest in it anymore.

Comment: This isn't what you asked, but I'd suggest [donating the car](http://www.goodwillcardonation.org/). You'll likely be better off than 35 bucks after you write off the donation on your next years taxes. A friend of mine did this recently and said it went pretty smooth as far as paperwork goes. No guessing like in this case.